# Difficulty setting display block in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, protractor

**My goal:**

In my page I have a dropdown that is with `display:none`, that is, I am not able to interact with this element if I do not define it as `display:block`

**The dropdown code:**

```
<dd id="preview_district" class="dd-true select-auto-scroll">
<div class="uk-width-small-1-1 uk-hidden-medium uk-hidden-large">
<div class="material-select filled">
<span class="material-title">Departamento</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="material-select filled" data-native-select="true" data-toggle-placeholder="true">
<label for="select-1-preview_district">
<span>(Selecciona)</span>
<strong></strong>
</label>
<input id="select-1-preview_district" type="checkbox">
<span class="material-title">Departamento</span>
<select id="selectPreviewDistrict" name="preview_district" placeholder="Departamento" data-native-select="true" data-toggle-placeholder="true">
<option value="*" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">(Selecciona)</option>
<option value="91">AMAZONAS</option>
<option value="5">ANTIOQUIA</option>
<option value="81">ARAUCA</option>
</select>
<ul class="radio">
<li>
<input id="preview_district-0" value="*" name="preview_district" type="radio">
<label for="preview_district-0">(Selecciona)</label>
</li>
<li>
<input id="preview_district-1" value="91" name="preview_district" type="radio">
<label for="preview_district-1">AMAZONAS</label>
</li>
<li>
</ul>
</div>
<small class="validation-msg uk-text-danger" data-field="preview_district" data-validation="invalid" style="display:none;">Selecciona el departamento</small>
</dd>
```

In this case, `<select id="selectPreviewDistrict" name="preview_district" placeholder="Departamento" data-native-select="true" data-toggle-placeholder="true">` is with `display:none`

**I'm trying to use:**

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].style.display = "block"', element(by.id('selectPreviewDistrict')).getWebElement());
```

but the element still is not visible.

Any help?

Comment: Why not directly style the dropdown with `display: block` with CSS, Any particular reason?

Comment: Which error did you get after you have set `display:block` and try to interact with it? Is it also visible, isn't there an other element in front of it? Or can you provide an example on jsfidle?